# Add days to date variable from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a date variable from SQL `$start`, but I need to add days to this variable with PHP. I did this for adding:

```
<?php
    $start = $start;
    //Incrementando 2 dias
    $jor2  = strtotime($start . "+ 1 days");
    echo date("d-m-Y", $jor2);
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong, but the result is: `19-03-2028` and my variable `$start` is `28-03-18`.

The output should be:

```
$start (28 / 03 / 2018) + 7 days, (04 / 04 / 2018)
```

Comment: "I have a date var from SQL" MySQL can also direcly add +1 day if the date format is 2018-04-05 for example...`SELECT '2018-04-05 ' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`  or `SELECT [column] + INTERVAL 1 DAY` with a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) cannot parse the [`d-m-y` format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

When the components separator is `-`, either you use 4-digits year (first or last component) or the year is the first component (4 or 2 digits).

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to tell the parser the format you are using:

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '28-03-18');
$end = $start->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

echo($end->format('d-m-Y'));
# 29-03-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Date coming from Mysql
$start = '2018-04-05';
$result = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . ' +1 day'));
var_dump($result);
```

**Update** after @axiac comment:

Since `$start` contains a date format different from Mysql's format, here is a way to transform it:

```
<?php
$start = '28-03-18';
list($d, $m, $y) = sscanf($start, '%d-%d-%d');
$start = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;
```

Comment: The value of `$start` used by the OP is `'28-03-18'`. How is your code better than the one posted in the question?